# Cannot get the Segmented control on the left side of a navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to add a UISegementedControl to the left side of a nav bar programmatically. I can get it to show in the middle by setting the control to the titleView as shown below. The following is the code that I have

```
NSArray *buttonNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", nil];
UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle =  UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

// instead of the following I would like to move to left side of the nav bar
self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:...]
```

?

---

To be more precise, maybe something like

```
UIBarButtonItem* item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
[item release];
```